# GridView dynamic column width in WPF

Tags: wpf, gridview, listview

```
<Window x:Class="GridViewSample.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" >
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Name="CheckoutList" Margin="0,0,8,0">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="CheckOutGridView">
                <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Style>
                </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock> 
                                <Hyperlink >          
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}"/> 
                                </Hyperlink> 
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock> 
                                <Hyperlink>          
                                    <TextBlock Text="Remove"/> 
                                </Hyperlink> 
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Width="100" Height="25" Click="Button_Click" >name</Button>
        <Button Width="100" Height="25" Click="Button_Click1" >long name</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    class TextObject
    {
        private string _text;

        public TextObject(string Text)
        {
            _text = Text;
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set { _text = value; }
        }
    }


    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckoutList.Items.Add(new TextObject("name"));
    }

    private void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckoutList.Items.Add(new TextObject("long name"));
    }

}
```

Given the above sample press name then long name.  How come the column doesn't resize to fit its contents?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<GridViewColumn Width="{x:Static System:Double.NaN}">
```

where

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

and this should help you resize the column to fit the header content.

Comment: It works, because setting the column width to NaN allows that column to measure to infinity, thus, filling up all the space of its parent container.

Comment: But isnt there a `Double.PositiveInfinity`? Is this behavior programmed in (as in somewhere they check `Double.IsNan(width)` and set it to `Auto` in the code of the `GridViewColumn`) or is it due to the nature of the `Double.Nan` itself?

Comment: This is not the nature of Double.NaN but the nature of WPF to measure its available width vs. container width. By setting column width to Double.NaN will 'fool' WPF by 'not setting a fixed width' and this creates an illusion of 'Auto' width.

Comment: Isn't this the same as `Width="Auto"` - at least, it is for me, as I get the same results.

Comment: @imekon As far as I know Width="Auto" has performance issue as it should wait for all rows to be loaded so it can define its Width. it's really not recommended on data columns.