# How to make a column extends on the width of the ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

In the following code:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" x:Name="lstRole" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
      MouseDoubleClick="lstRole_MouseDoubleClick">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Role ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Role Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The result is:

[image]

I don't know where is the third column come from !!

The question is: **How to make the second column "RoleName" extends on the width of the ListView?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501161/gridview-dynamic-column-width-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

I used [RangeColumn](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/ListView_layout_manager.aspx?msg=3045194) control in one of my applications and it worked very well.

You can use this control to set something like this

```
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Role ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Role Name" ctrl:RangeColumn.IsFillColumn="true" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
    </GridView>
```